# Why I can't add new repositories using gitosis?

Tags: git, gitosis

I set up gitosis but even when i can clone, pull and push to the gitosis-admin repo, i can't create new ones.

According to every doc i read, to create a new repo one has to:

- Give user write access to the repo (inside a group put: writable = repo-name)
- The user create a repo locally add a remote then does a push
- The repo is created in the server

But i always get the error `fatal: 'repo-name.git' does not appear to be a git repository`

But if a login on the server (as user git) and create the repo manually using `mkdir repo-name.git && cd repo-name.git && git --bare init`, then i can push from my local repo to the remote one.

Comment: When you say "i always get the error `fatal: 'repo' does not appear to be a git repository`", when does this error occur?  When creating the repo locally or when pushing the local repo to the gitosis server?  What it the exact error?

Comment: When pushing the local repo to gitosis.

The error is (something like):
'repo-name.git' does not appear to be a git repository
The remote end hung.

But i suspect is a damage installation because in ubuntu 9.04 it's working good. And in OS X 10.5.8 and ubuntu 8.10 not

Comment: Gitosis is no longer supported.   You should consider switching to gitolite.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem and I found out if I change the way I access the repository, it worked. After you have created the group writeable.

```sh
# Go to the directory you want to start your project in.
git init; git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git remote add origin gitosis@[server]:gitosis-test.git
git push --all
```

So to recap before I was doing gitosis@[server]/gitosis-test.git and that was failing. I swapped the semicolon and it worked.

Props on the loglevel = DEBUG
It helped a lot to find out what was happening.

Comment: The key statement here is the use of `/` instead of `:`. Git probably ought to accept either.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
In your gitosis-admin repo, try adding `loglevel = DEBUG` under `[gitosis]` in your `gitosis.conf`.  Push this change to your server and then try again.  This will generate a lot of useful information to help debug the problem.

[These instructions from Dreamhost](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Gitosis#Adding_a_Repository_and_.28optional.29_User) are the best I found.

Are you pushing the `gitosis-admin` repo after updating permissions?

Comment: Yes, and it's updating the config in the gitosis server, I've also made sure the post-update hook was executable...

Comment: What I don't know is if gitosis should make the new repo when it's configuration is updated, I mean, I update the config and push, I see the config is updated on the server BUT i don't see the new bare repo created, but i don't know if this is the way is supposed to work?

Comment: @Cesar: Simply updating the configuration in `gitosis.conf` does not create the repository on the server.  To do that, you must create the repo locally and then push it to the server using `git push origin master:refs/heads/master`.

Comment: but actually, git push origin master:refs/heads/master didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i've had exactly the same problem just today.

I checked by

$ ssh git@yourserver echo if you see this, it is not gitosis

and found out that gitosis was not servicing ssh sessions.

I couldnt get why.

As a solution a deleted git user (that i used for gitosis purposes) with its home folder and recreated it from scratch.

And it helped.

README.rst from gitosis.git says

".. warning::

```
    For now, ``gitosis`` uses the ``HOME`` environment variable to
    locate where to write its files. If you use ``sudo -u``
    without ``-H``, ``sudo`` will leave the old value of ``HOME``
    in place, and this will cause trouble. There will be a
    workaround for that later on, but for now, always remember to
    use ``-H`` if you're sudoing to the account.
```

You should always edit the configuration file via `git`. The file
symlinked to `~/.gitosis.conf` on the server will be overwritten
when pushing changes to the `gitosis-admin.git` repository.
"
i suppose it might be the cause..